# How can I solve a modular equation with no modular inverse (but there's a solution)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

While reading a book about cryptography, I stumbled across the following calculations:

$k_1\equiv \overline{(5\times24-22\times5)}(24\times21-22\times5)$ modulo $26$,

where $\overline{x}$ denotes a multiplicative inverse.

The book skipped the calculations and gave the correct solution which you can check

$k_1\equiv3$ modulo $26$

The problem is that, if you simplify the first congruence, you get:

$k_1\equiv \overline{10} \times 394 \equiv \overline{10} \times 4$ modulo $26$

And, since $GCD(10, 26)=2\ne1$, there is no multiplicative inverse for $\overline{10}$ modulo $26$.

So, how can I solve such equation and what am I missing here involving the multiplicative inverses?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  I don't understand what you mean by "you can check" it.  How do you check it when it seems that $\overline{10}$ is undefined?

Comment: If you multiply both sides by 10 and cancel out the inv(10), you can check that 3 times 10 is congruent to 4 modulo 26.

Comment: Well then, what they did is interpret the original equation as meaning $10k_1\equiv4\pmod{26}$ which is solvable by standard methods.    I think that's a stretch, though.  They also missed $k_1=16$, apparently.

Comment: $10k_1\equiv4\pmod{26}\iff5k_1\equiv2\pmod{13}\iff k_1\equiv3\pmod{13}\iff $ $k_1\equiv3$ or $16\pmod{26}$

Comment: Yes, since $10$ is not invertible mod $26$ it is ill-defined. The solution of $\,10k\equiv 386\equiv 4\pmod{26}\,$ is $k\equiv 3\pmod{\!13}\,$  $\iff k\equiv 3,16\pmod{\!16}$. Further context is required to know which solution is intended. Without such your question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve $10k_1\equiv4\pmod{26}, $ though $10$ does not have an inverse mod $26$,

divide through by $2$ to get $5k_1\equiv2\pmod{13}$.  $5$ has an inverse mod $13$ (it's $8$),

so $5k_1\equiv2\pmod{13}$ means $k_1\equiv3\pmod{13}$.

That translates to $k_1\equiv3$ or $16\pmod{26}$.